# Apply function to subset elements that satisfy a criteria across subset of columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the data.table, `exampleDT`,

```
set.seed(7)
exampleDT = data.table(colA = rnorm(10,15,5),
                       colB = runif(10,100,150),
                       targetA = rnorm(10,12,2),
                       targetB = rnorm(10,8,4))
```

If I want to calculate the mean of all elements in column `targetA`, for example, that are below some threshold -- say, 10 -- I can do the following:

```
examp_threshold = 10
exampleDT[targetA<examp_threshold,mean(targetA)]
# [1] 9.224007566814299
```

And if I want to calculate the mean of all elements in columns `targetA` and `targetB`, for example, I can do the following:

```
target_cols = names(exampleDT)[which(names(exampleDT) %like% "target")] 
exampleDT[,lapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=target_cols]
#              targetA           targetB
# 1: 12.60101574551183 7.585007905896557
```

But I don't know how to combine the two; that is, to calculate the mean of all elements in all columns containing a specified string ("target", in this case) that are below some specified threshold (10, here). This was my first guess, but it was unsuccessful:

```
exampleDT[.SD<examp_threshold,lapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=target_cols]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: targetA,targetB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subset in the `j` expression, like so:

```
exampleDT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x[x<examp_threshold])),.SDcols=target_cols]

#   targetA targetB
#1: 9.224008 6.66624
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!